# count equal values in 2 strings that have unique values (no repeated values) recursively

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a recursive function that takes to strings each string dos not have repeated value and the function count the number of values that appear in both strings
for example "1234" is a  value that can be passed to the function while "12343" does have 2 "3" in it

the funtion i wrote is

```
int func(char* str1,char* str2)
{
    if(*str1 == '\0' || *str2 == '\0') return 0;

    if(*str1 == *str2) return 1 + func(str1+1,str2+1) ;
    else return (func(str1,str2+1) + func(str1+1, str2))  ;
}
```

it doesn't work in every situation

Example 
str1 = "12346", str2 = "74321", result 4

Comment: Please give an example of the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Are those strings "sorted" (like "01367" or "1234")? Is "12343" an example of a string that can **not** be passed?

Comment: The first `if` stops if either string reaches the end. That is, `func("12345", "")` will return `0`. Is that intended or should it continue to operate on the non-empty string? I guess I'm unclear what exactly the relation between the two strings is supposed to be as you have not explained that clearly.

Comment: @Bob__ the string are not sorted

Comment: @kaylum updated the question with your instructions

Comment: One way: search for the first letter of the second string in the first string (ie `strchr`) and then add in result of recursively calling `func` with the second string moved forward one letter.

Comment: Why particularly does this have to be a recursive function?

Comment: @kaylum thanks for your answer but i actually forgot to mention that i should not use any built in function

Comment: That was just an example. Can do it without strchr. Just iterate the first string looking for the first letter of second string. The full function is still recursive as it then calls `func` again with the second string moved up 1 char.